# Efficiently Tracking User Views of Horse Pairs in Firebase - Seeking Better Solutions

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app where users can check out pairs of horses and vote on their favorites. Each horse is stored as a document in a 'horse' collection, with details like 'race,' 'age,' 'gender,' and 'color.' These horse pairs are shown side by side for user evaluation.

**Problem:**

I'm grappling with a challenge: I need to keep tabs on whether a user has seen a particular horse pair before, and whether they're interested or not. The catch is that I can't rely on local storage since users can clear their cache, potentially causing déjà vu with the same pairs.

**Current Idea:**

One idea on my mind is to create a new 'HorseBuyer' collection. In this collection, each document would be tagged with the user's UID. Within each user's document, I'm thinking of crafting a 'Horse_Pair_ID' that combines the UIDs of the two horses in a pair. Plus, I'd add a 'viewed' field to note when the user last saw that pair.

**Requirements:**
Efficiently keep track of viewed horse pairs.
Ensure accurate tracking even when users revisit the app.
Keep Firebase read and write operations in check.
Allow users to see new, never-seen-before horse pairs.
Sidestep the reliance on local storage due to potential cache clearing.
Expected Result:

The aim is to create a solid solution that lets users smoothly view horse pairs while accurately noting pairs they've seen. The solution should be efficient, maintainable, and capable of handling a sizable user base.

**Pros of the Current Idea:**
Detailed tracking of user interaction with horse pairs.
Harnesses Firebase's real-time capabilities for instant updates.
Simplifies managing user-specific data.

**Cons of the Current Idea:**
Potential uptick in Firebase read and write operations, which could raise cost concerns.
Complexity in managing and querying the 'HorseBuyer' collection, especially at scale.

**Exploring Alternatives:**
Considering the concerns tied to Firebase's read/write usage, I'm keen to explore alternative methods for efficiently tracking viewed horse pairs. If you've got any ideas, suggestions, or alternative approaches that can achieve this goal while mitigating the potential downsides of the current idea, I'd greatly appreciate your insights.

I haven't found a solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

> One idea on my mind is to create a new 'HorseBuyer' collection. In this collection, each document would be tagged with the user's UID. Within each user's document, I'm thinking of crafting a 'Horse_Pair_ID' that combines the UIDs of the two horses in a pair.

You tagged your question with [firebase-realtime-database](/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database) but you're talking here about [google-cloud-firestore](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore). While both are a part of Firebase, both are two different products, with two different mechanisms. Aside from that, your idea sounds good to me.

> **Pros of the Current Idea: ** Detailed tracking of user interaction with horse pairs. Harnesses Firebase's real-time capabilities for instant updates. Simplifies managing user-specific data.

Yes, in both cases, Firestore and the Realtime Database offer client SDKs, so you can benefit from the ability to get updates in real time.

> **Cons of the Current Idea: **Potential uptick in Firebase read and write operations, which could raise cost concerns. Complexity in managing and querying the 'HorseBuyer' collection, especially at scale.

Besides the fact that each Firebase database works differently, both have different billing mechanisms. It's true that when you write data in Firestore you're charged for that write operation, however, in the Realtime Database the write operation it's free of charge. So it's up to you to decide which solution fits best to your use case.